# Invoke function still trow an exception for cross thread operation

Tags: c#, windows

I find a simple example for collecting information from an industrial equipment via MTConnect standard and adapted to my equipment. The example received periodically, via network, a variable lenght text buffer and display in a listbox. I modify the original code to display meaningfull information by searching and parsing the received buffer to be display in textbox and progress bar.The receiving function, running on an event, is the following:

```
public void OnRecievedData( IAsyncResult ar )
{
    Socket sock = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

    // Check if any data was received
    try
    {
        int nBytesRec = sock.EndReceive( ar );
        if( nBytesRec > 0 )
        {
            // Add the data to the List
            string sRecieved = Encoding.ASCII.GetString( m_byBuff, 0, nBytesRec );
                    //sRecieved = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(m_byBuff, 0, nBytesRec);

                    // WARNING : The following line is NOT thread safe. Invoke is
                    // m_lbRecievedData.Items.Add( sRecieved );
                    //Invoke( m_AddMessage, new string [] { sRecieved } );
                    Invoke(myDelegate, sRecieved);
                    // If the connection is still usable restablish the callback
                    SetupRecieveCallback( sock );
        }
        else
        {
            // If no data was recieved then the connection is probably dead
            Console.WriteLine( "Client {0}, disconnected", sock.RemoteEndPoint );
            sock.Shutdown( SocketShutdown.Both );
            sock.Close();
        }
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        MessageBox.Show( this, ex.Message, "Unknown error on Recieve!" );
    }
}
```

**m_AddMessage** process the RX buffer and fill in the most simpler example just **m_lbRecieveData** list box while in my code the buffer is first parse then the interesting data display in variuos text box.

As seen in commented lines, I try to use **Invoke** directly on **m_AddMessage** function then in the latest try using a **delegate**. The code run correctly for a variable length of time then trow an exception :

> Cross-thread operation not valid: FormMain accessed from a thread
> other than the thread it was created on

No helpfull information on which thread raised the exception are available. I search any info related to the problem (include this forum) and follow several example on using Invoke but I always obtain the same result. I really appreciate any help on resolving this issue

Comment: Use the debugger, the Debug > Windows > Threads window shows on what thread the invoked code runs.

Comment: Invoke directly against the ListBox, like this: `m_lbRecievedData.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { m_lbRecievedData.Items.Add(sRecieved); });`

Comment: Inside m_AddMessage every components get its data in this manner:                         if (m_tbTotOnTime.InvokeRequired)
                            m_tbTotOnTime.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => m_tbTotOnTime.Text = str));
                        else
                            m_tbTotOnTime.Text = str;
The exception get thrown before m_AddMessage is call. I put a breakpoint on every call to InvokeRequired but it never stop. The exception get thrown before.